# Integrating polynomial fraction of same degree

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm to integrate:

$$ \int {\frac{x^2}{x^2+x-2} }dx$$

If there was a constant in the numerator then I could solve this but I'm not sure with $x^2$. Can I use long division? I  tried and it didn't seem to work out (but my long division is very rusty).

Answer (score 3):

$$\int {x^2\over x^2+x-2}dx=\int {x^2+x-2-x+2\over x^2+x-2}dx=\int1+{-x+2\over x^2+x-2}dx$$

$$=x-{1\over2}\int{2x-4\over x^2+x-2}dx=x-{1\over2}(\int{2x+1\over x^2+x-2}-{5\over x^2+x-2}dx)$$
$$=x-{1\over2}ln( x^2+x-2)+{5\over2}\int{1\over x^2+x-2}dx $$

After that you need to deal with $$\int{1\over x^2+x-2}dx=\int{1\over (x+2)(x-1)}dx $$
$$={1\over3} \int {1\over(x-1)}-{1\over(x+2)}dx={1\over3}(ln(x-1)-ln(x+2))+c$$

Total result is $$=x-{1\over2}ln( x^2+x-2)+{5\over6}(ln({x-1\over x+2}))+c $$
we are done.

Comment: What is happening when you pull $x$ out of the integral in your 4th step? Didn't realize you could even do that..?

Comment: He just integrates the $1$ quickly to give $x$ and so it appears out of the integral

Comment: @Paze:integral of sums is equal to sum of integrals, you can write $\int 1+f(x) dx=x+\int f(x)dx$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+x-2} = 1 - \dfrac{x-2}{x^2+x-2}$

Comment: Do I use long division on $ \frac{x-2}{x^2+x-2} $ then?

Comment: Partial fractions